# React SVG not rerendering on attribute update

Tags: reactjs, svg, filter, attributes, jsx

I'm updating an SVG filter attribute via a slider input control but it doesn't continuously update the rendered filter.

Here is the working code: https://codepen.io/dgwyer/pen/EXmqrb

If I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to set the filter then it works but this hack isn't good enough to use in production code?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { blur: 2 };
    this.blurChange = this.blurChange.bind(this);
  }

  blurChange(event) {
    this.setState({ blur: Number(event.target.value) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 0 0">
          <filter id="outline"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `<feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="${this.state.blur}" />`
            }}
          />
          <filter id="outline1">
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation={this.state.blur} />`
          </filter>            
        </svg>
        <h1 className="fe">Working</h1>
        <div className="control"><input type="range" min="0" max="50" onChange={this.blurChange} value={this.state.blur} /><h3>Blur Slider</h3></div>
        <h1 className="fe1">Not Working</h1>
        <div className="control"><input type="range" min="0" max="50" onChange={this.blurChange} value={this.state.blur} /><h3>Blur Slider</h3></div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Is there anyway to update an SVG filter attribute as you normally would with React without using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` hack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting, apparently the `<feGaussianBlur />` has to be re-mounted for changes to apply correctly and React doesn't re-mount it but only updates the `stdDeviation` attribute. To fix it use `key` prop additionally on `<feGaussianBlur />` so that React re-mounts it each time `this.state.blur` changes:

```
<filter id="outline1">
  <feGaussianBlur key={this.state.blur} stdDeviation={this.state.blur} />
</filter>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work and means the ugly `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` hack isn't needed. What's even more interesting is that it doesn't seem to matter if you set the key on the SVG filter primitive OR the HTML element it's applied to. Not sure I understand what's going on behind the scenes though if the key is on the HTML element. How would that trigger an SVG primitive remount? Is it because they are linked, and updating the key on either one forces a remount? I've updated the pen to include both scenarios: https://codepen.io/dgwyer/pen/EXmqrb

Comment: It doesn't trigger SVG primitive to remount. The point is we need to trigger a browser to reapply styles on that HTML element. So you can trigger it by remounting both SVG or HTML element.

Basically, they are linked using your CSS styles (has nothing to do with React). When you remount HTML element which these styles are applied to then of course browser recalculates the styles for it and re-renders.