# React SVG Component Not Always Updating

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-hooks, attributes, jsx

I'm currently having an SVG object composed of a list of "blocks" that changes based on a Select selection. The problem that I have is that the shape of the blocks only appear to update when the number of blocks in the selected plan is different.

So, for example, if I start with PlanA and it consists of 2 blocks, selecting PlanB with 3 blocks will give me the result I expect. But if I then select PlanC that also has 3 blocks, the dimensions of these blocks doesn't change (though the accompanying text does).

An example for what I've done with the top level component:

```
            const [planOptions, setPlanOptions] = useState([]); //would be filled with option info
        const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
        const [fullInfo, setFullInfo] = useState([]); //would contain the full selection of information
        const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState([]);
        
        <PlanChartArea
            key={blocks}
            blocks={blocks}
        />
        
        function selectPlan(fullInfo, planVal) {
            //get blocks by chosing correct plan and ignoring the initial "marker" element
            let blockList = fullInfo.filter(elem => elem.plan == planVal && elem.point > 1); 
            //
            ////////
            //----PERFORM TRANSFORMATIONS
            ////////
            //
            setBlocks(blockList);
        }

        const handleSelectChange = (option) => {
            setSelectedOption(option);
            var selection = option.value;
            selectPlan(fullInfo, selection);

        }
        
        <Select
            value={selectedOption}
            placeholder="Select Plan..."
            options={planOptions}
            onChange={(e) => { handleSelectChange(e) }}
        />
```

And with the child component:

```
for (let i = 0; i < props.blocks.length; i++) {
        blocksobj.push(<Block
            key={i + "_bl"}
            x1={props.blocks[i].x1pos}
            x2={props.blocks[i].x2pos}
            y1={props.blocks[i].y1pos}
            y2={props.blocks[i].y2pos}
            y0={y0}
            maxYValue={maxYValue}
            yLength={yLength}
        />);
        blocktxt.push(<text
            key={i + "_bt"}
            x={asPercent(x1pos + 0.5 * (x2pos - x1pos))}
            y={asPercent(y0 + 0.05 * yLength)}
            fontWeight="bold"
            dominantBaseline="auto"
            textAnchor="middle"
            >
            {Math.round(props.blocks[i].value)/100}kg/min
        </text>);
    }
        
return (
    <div style={{position:"parent", width:"100%", height:"100%"}}>
        <svg width={asPercent(SVG_WIDTH)} height={asPercent(SVG_HEIGHT)}>

            {blocksobj}
            {blocktxt} 
            <XYAxis
                xAxisLength={xLength}
                yAxisLength={yLength}
                ox={x0}
                oy={y0}
            />
            {xTickmarks}
            {yTickmarks}         
 
        </svg>
    </div>
);
```

I tried implementing the accepted solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420535/react-svg-not-rerendering-on-attribute-update) but to no effect. Perhaps this is because my state value is in the form of an Array? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are `blocksobj` and `blockstxt` defined in the child component? Can you post the complete component code?

Comment: I can't really post the complete component as a lot of other things are going on (this is a very simplified version that highlights the specific bits I'm looking at). ```blocksobj``` and ```blockstxt``` are just blank arrays to start with, with the text and shape objects pushed into them.